# extjs 4 How to pass function in JSON String

Tags: extjs4

I am creating portal using JSON string.

Something like

```
    appPortalItems.add({ 
        id: PortletID,
        collapsed: true,
        title: PortletTitle,
        height: PortletHeight,
        tools: getToolsBar(String),
        html: htmlContent,
        listeners: {
            'close': Ext.bind(panel.onPortletClose, panel),
            'endDrag': Ext.bind(panel.onPortletDrag, panel),
            'resize': Ext.bind(panel.onPortletResize, panel)
        }
     });
```

So in the above code there is tools : getToolBar(String)

Here I am passing String , which is nothing but JSON.

```
 "max": {
      "type": "maximize",
      "handler": function(e,target,panelHeader,tool){
        userMaximize(e,target,panelHeader,tool)
      }
    }
```

userMaximize is my function , I want to call this when user click on the Menu item.

SO I have not added "" to the function (e , etc..
In Chrome and FF it is working fine. But in IE it is giving me error.

Please suggest How can I pass function as a object in JSON so that on Menu Item click event userMaximize will get execute ?

Comment: what are you trying by passing function as string?

Comment: I am trying to create the portlet using add function. and for the add function I am passing all the portlet attribute as Json.. but when I check the Json using some Json validator it is giving me error, but it works fine in Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: Sadly afaik json data structure doesn't allow you to pass functions as values. You might need `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use tools , write some code like this

```
tools:[{
    type:'maximize',
    tooltip: 'maximize !',      
    handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
        userMaximize(e,target,panelHeader,tool)// check the parameters passed
    }
},
{
    type:'help',
    tooltip: 'Get Help',
    handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
        // show help here
    }
}]
```

Comment: But How can I pass this in JSON as a string to the add function?